# Giving a default text to which divs can fall back

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that my `div`'s content go back to before it was altered when `input` is empty? I'm doing this because people may just erase `input` and the div would also be empty.

```js
let target = $('#toBeChanged');
let tracked = $('#tracked');

tracked.keyup(function() {
  if (!tracked.val()) {
    //I want it to fall back to 'Default Text'
    return;
  }
  
  target.text(tracked.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "tracked" type = "text">

<div id = "toBeChanged">
  Default Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `CSS` and whenever `div` get `empty` show `before` content.

So there is no need to check `input` value anymore. if `value` length is > 0, `div` is not `empty` and `value` will be shown and if `value` is nothing (`''`) `div` will be `empty` and `CSS` will show default text.

```js
let target = $('#toBeChanged');
let tracked = $('#tracked');

tracked.keyup(function() {
  target.text(tracked.val());
});
```

```css
#toBeChanged:empty::before {
  content: 'Default Text';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "tracked" type = "text">

<div id = "toBeChanged"></div>
```

hope to help.

Comment: Wow this is a really clever solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a variable then use it when no valid text is provided:

```js
let defaultText = 'Default Text';
let target = $('#toBeChanged');
let tracked = $('#tracked');

tracked.keyup(function() {
  if (!tracked.val()) {
    //I want it to fall back to 'Default Text'
    target.text(defaultText);
    return;
  }
  
  target.text(tracked.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "tracked" type = "text">

<div id = "toBeChanged">
  Default Text
</div>
```

Comment: I see. I did do that. However, I considered it rather unelegant? I was wondering if there was a fall-back mechanism like how we can alter CSS using JS and reverting it to the original css. E.g. `$(element).css('display', 'none')` and when we want it to go back to how it was previously, `$(element).css('display', '')`.

As for your solution, won't it be more effective if I wrote `let defaultText = $('#toBeChanged').text()` instead? This way, even when I change the default, I won't have to change the JS?

Comment: It _is_ rather unelegant; but there's not really an elegant way to do this with jQuery. You can indeed use the initial text value of the element to set the variable, if that's what you want the text to be

Comment: I see. Is there another way to do this using something other than jQuery then?

Comment: There are frameworks which would make that kind of thing much easier, though admittedly they come with a certain amount of overhead which may be undesirable, depending on your use case. Popular examples at the moment are React, Vue, and Angular

Comment: I see. My current assignments are still focused on solely using JS and jQuery. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stash the value on initialization.

```
let target = $('#toBeChanged');
let tracked = $('#tracked');
let defaultText = target.text();

tracked.keyup(function() {
  if (!tracked.val()) {
    //I want it to fall back to 'Default Text'
    target.text(defaultText);
    return;
  }

  target.text(tracked.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `target.text("Default text");` in your `if` statement. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdWxMQ).

```
let target = $('#toBeChanged');
let tracked = $('#tracked');

tracked.keyup(function() {
  if (!tracked.val()) {
    //I want it to fall back to 'Default Text'
    target.text("Default Text");
    return;
  }

  target.text(tracked.val());
});
```